# An improper integral and a related volume calculation

Tags: improper-integrals, volume, residue-calculus

I am trying to solve Whittaker & Watson's Chap 6, Misc Example 6.13. I understand the formula to be
$$
\int_0^\infty \left( \frac {\sin t} t \right)^n \,dt = \frac{\pi}{2^n (n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} (-1)^k {n\choose k} (n-2k)^{n-1}.
$$

Through a trick, I brought this to an equivalent calculation that the Euclidean **volume** of a portion of the $(n-1)$-dimensional cube
$$
\{(x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\,|\, -1\leq x_i\leq 1, -1\leq x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1}\leq 1\} 
$$
is
$$
\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} (-1)^k {n\choose k} (n-2k)^{n-1}.
$$

I can check the volume calculation for $n$ up to 4, and $(n-1)$ up to 3, but I don't know how to proceed in general.

Help with either proof would be appreciated, and it would imply the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Using the binomial theorem, write

$$\begin{align}
\sin^n(z)&=\left(\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\right)^n\\\\
&=\frac1{(2i)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}e^{i(n-2k)z}
\end{align}$$

Now, apply the residue theorem.  Be careful to close the plane in the upper half plane for $n>2k$ and in the lower half plane for $n<2k$.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. It is a nice calculation then. In a sense, the book got the formula wrong, and the sum for $k$ from 0 to $[n/2]$ and from $[n/2]+1$ to $n$ are negative of each other. Then your comment about switching direction adds them correctly. Nice!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure